# Automatically sending "Reset Password Reset" on user account registration

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages, user-registration, email-verification

When adding a new user, the verification email needs sending manually from the WP 'Users' / 'All Users' dialogue box – as in *"Edit | Delete | View | Send password reset | Approve"*

Users can set themselves up at any time of the night or day and obviously won't want to have to wait for an administrator to trigger that email.

Naively, I was hoping for a switch ... and maybe there is, but I can't see one.

Using WP-generated dashboard, SysBasics' "Customise my Account", SBThemes' "WooCommerce Email Verification" and Elementor/ElementsKit

Looked through all files related to the plug-ins that look like they might have supplanted the stock WooCommerce "Default Forms" based on "Inspect"ing the code. Contacted SysBasics and am waiting a response (on the offchance that they might have any ideas). Also looked through a range of .php files in search of quick fixes.